# How to assign values from text file to visual studio c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am creating another solution from a website [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830433.aspx) using visual studio 2015 c# (with some modifications to the code).

The xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestApplication.InsertPushpin"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
    Width="1024" Height="768">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <m:Map CredentialsProvider="INSERT_YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY">
        </m:Map>
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

The xaml.cs file is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Design;

namespace WPFTestApplication
{
public partial class AddPushpinToMap : Window
{
    LocationConverter locConverter = new LocationConverter();

public AddPushpinToMap()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
    pin.Location = new Location(37.1481402218342, -119.644248783588);

    // Adds the pushpin to the map.
    myMap.Children.Add(pin);

  }
 }
}
```

I have a text file which contains float values in this format:

```
 1.234
 145.765
 1.267
 145.957
```

The first value is the latitude and the 2nd value is the longitude.
This repeats for the 3rd and 4th, 5th and 6th etc.

I want to assign the 1st and 2nd values from the textfile to the line of code

```
     pin.Location = new Location(1st_value,2nd_value);
```

and then it will add a pushpin to the map.

But I'm a newbie and I'm not sure how to read from the text file and add the value to that line of code.

How can I assign the values from the text file to the line of code?

Thanks

Comment: Another strange world question. :)

Comment: Thanks for your replies :) My code is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `File.ReadLines` method to read the file contents.

As a beginner you could start iterating over list using `foreach`.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath).ToList();
var locations = new List<Location>();
if(lines.Count() %2 !=0 ) throw new ArgumentException("invalid no.of vertices");

for(int i=0;i<lines.Count();i+=2)
{
    double lat = double.Parse(lines[i]);
    double lon = double.Parse(lines[i+1]);

    locations.Add(new Location(lat, lon));
}
```

If you are familiar with `Linq` you could do this with `Linq` as below.

```
var locations = File.ReadLines(filepath)
    .Select((line,i)=> new {line, index=i/2 })
    .GroupBy(x=>x.index)
    .Select(x=> new Location( double.Parse(x.First().line),double.Parse(x.Last().line)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should give you something to start with,

```
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("*** your filepath ***"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                double lat = double.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                double lon = double.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

                pin.Location = new Location(lat, lon);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:
Use `File.ReadAllLines` to get all Lines(as Array) from the File. As per your input specifications the `latitude` will be in the First Line and the `longitude` will be at the second line, so that you can access them through their index. use `double.TryParse()` method to convert those values into double equivalent. Now consider the following code for this:

```
string textFilePath=@"local path to the file";
var Lines= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textFilePath);
double latitude,longitude;
double.TryParse(Lines[0],out latitude);
double.TryParse(Lines[1],out longitude); 
 pin.Location = new Location(latitude,longitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you read the file content, you could maintain collection of all the Latitude and Longitude information in `List`, and each list item would be pair of Latitude and Longitude values. `Tuple` should solve the purpose here.

```
    private void BuildGeoInfo()
    {
        string textFilePath = @"path to your text file";

        //Read all the contents of file as list of lines
        var fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textFilePath).ToList();

        //This list will hold the Latitude and Longitude information in pairs
        List<Tuple<double, double>> latLongInfoList = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();

        int index = 0;
        while (index < fileLines.Count)
        {
            var latLongInfo = new Tuple<double, double>(
                                  Convert.ToDouble(fileLines[index]),
                                  //++ to index to get value of next line 
                                  Convert.ToDouble(fileLines[index++]));

            latLongInfoList.Add(latLongInfo);

            index++; //++ to index to move to next line
        }
    }
```

You can then use the data in collection like this for example -

```
var latitude = latLongInfoList.First().Item1;
var longitude = latLongInfoList.First().Item2;
pin.Location = new Location(latitude,longitude);
```

Do check for the corner cases and handle them accordingly, like what if the lines are not in multiplier of two, type of each text line etc.